# thinking-sphinx: indexing ok, querying gets "No response from searchd" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have this error in development env, using thinking-sphinx search in my controller or with console

```
> Product.search "moule"
Riddle::ResponseError: No response from searchd (status: , version: )
```

The service is up (rake ts:start), and running (ps aux|grep shows the searchd process with my development config file).

The search seems to work using search command line :

```
search --config /Users/yyy/workspace/xxx/config/development.sphinx.conf moule
```

gets me all the matching products

```
index 'product_core': query 'moule ': returned 17 matches of 17 total in 0.000 sec
```

I tried to restart my rails application or searchd and also reindex, I can't make it work!

Here is my configuration :

```
development:
  morphology: libstemmer_french
  enable_star: true
  html_strip: true
  min_prefix_len: 4
  min_infix_len: 0
  charset_type: utf-8
```

I'm using

```
rails (2.3.8)
thinking-sphinx (1.3.20) / riddle 1.2.2
sphinx 0.9.9
```

(edit)
It looks like the problem could come from my define index instruction. I reverted some changed I made, rebuilt the index and the error does not appear any more. The problem isn't fix because

```
> Product.search "moule"
```

does not return any result (there should be).
A few days ago, everything was working fine :-S

(edit) here is the searchd --status result :

```
searchd status
--------------
uptime: 85351 
connections: 1 
maxed_out: 0 
command_search: 0 
command_excerpt: 0 
command_update: 0 
command_keywords: 0 
command_persist: 0 
command_status: 1 
agent_connect: 0 
agent_retry: 0 
queries: 0 
dist_queries: 0 
query_wall: 0.000 
query_cpu: OFF 
dist_wall: 0.000 
dist_local: 0.000 
dist_wait: 0.000 
query_reads: OFF 
query_readkb: OFF 
query_readtime: OFF 
avg_query_wall: 0.000 
avg_query_cpu: OFF 
avg_dist_wall: 0.000 
avg_dist_local: 0.000 
avg_dist_wait: 0.000 
avg_query_reads: OFF 
avg_query_readkb: OFF 
avg_query_readtime: OFF
```

Comment: Could you please provide output for "searchd --status"? And have you tried to upgrade at least to 2.0.2 version?

Comment: The `search` command line tool doesn't actually talk to the daemon - it cheats and reads directly from the index files itself.

Comment: Sphinx 0.9.9-release (r2117)
    Copyright (c) 2001-2009, Andrew Aksyonoff

    FATAL: no readable config file (looked in /usr/local/Cellar/sphinx/0.9.9/etc/sphinx.conf, ./sphinx.conf).

Comment: Actually my config was working, the problem appeared when I tried to configure thinking sphinx. I tried to upgrade to 2.0.3 but I wasnt sure that it would work with thinking sphinx. I reinstalled the original version.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue, but for some reason doing the following worked

```
/usr/local/bin/indexer --rotate product_core --config config/development.sphinx.conf
```

You'll of course have to edit the path to the sphinx config and the path to indexer.  I actually have no idea what's going on, but it fixed it just the same

Comment: this worked for me but my path to indexer was /usr/bin/indexer (found this out by running `whereis indexer` at my command line also "product_core" should be replaced with the name of your index, if you look inside your sphinx conf it should tell you what it is